# laptops display tinted orange

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, display, nvidia-graphics-card

I've had my Asus laptop for about two years now, and yesterday about 5 minutes after I turned on my laptop, the screen suddenly flashed orange. I thought it was a trick of the light at first, but I noticed that my colleague's computers were all still appearing as normal. I figured it would just be a momentary problem, so I restarted my computer and it appeared to be gone, but then a few minutes later there it was again, this weird orange tint on my screen.

I checked my two display drivers:

- Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 745M

And disabled both individually in device manager (I still haven't dared to disable both), but the problem remains there.

The only reason I can think of is my much younger cousin installed and tried to play Minecraft on my laptop yesterday, and about half an hour after that I turned my computer back on, and the orange tint came on a few minutes after that.

When I hibernate my computer and turn it back on, the orange tint stays there from the login screen, but when I shut down / restart it, the orange tint goes way for a while and then comes back on.

Anything I can do to further analyse this problem?

Comment: Does this only happen with the internal screen (if so it might be a dammaged LCD or a loose cable), or does the tint also show up on external displays (which makes a bad or failed GU more likely).

Comment: Run Memtest86+.  A key goal here isn't just to test memory; it is to run the system outside of Windows, which may help to indicate if any Windows driver is at issue.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe check if you have a program called flux installed on your pc it can tint it orange.